# Not booting with new PCIE 4.0 NVME disk

Tags: boot, ssd, desktop

I have PRIME X570-PRO and recently bought a WD BLACK SN850 NVMe disk.

When I install it I don't get past the bios logo screen (where it says press DEL to enter bios).
Pressing del or F2 doesn't work either.

I've tried it in both M2 slots and with/without my other M2 disk. Nothing helps.
I got four disks in total, two "regular" SSDs and two M2s (the new one included).

Currently mounted drives (all Samsung):

- 850 PRO 512GB
- 860 QVO 1TB
- 970 EVO 250GB

Comment: NVMe typically requires UEFI.  UEFI, when you have Windows installs, requires GPT.  So make sure you have UEFI enabled.

Comment: This is my second nvme. The first one has windows installed and runs fine.

Comment: Are you sure your current M.2 drive is NVMe cause it sounds like it might be SATA

Comment: I've listed them now. The last one is NVMe.